# WP_Error with get_category_parents

Tags: fatal-error

I get this error in my theme:

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in `/home/winentra/public_html/s1.ssonline.co.in/wp-content/themes/peekaboo/admin/common-functions.php` on line 186

Line No. 186:

```
echo get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');
```

Context:

```
 elseif ( is_single() ) {
          $cat = get_the_category(); 
              $cat = $cat[0];
          echo get_category_parents($cat, TRUE, ' ' . $delimiter . ' ');
          echo $currentBefore;
          the_title();
          echo $currentAfter;
}
```

Any ideas on this please?

Answer (score 1):

If you call `get_the_category()` without a parameter you have to use it in a loop – after `the_post();` was called. Otherwise `get_the_category()` returns `FALSE` and `get_category_parents()` returns a `WP_Error` object … which is lacking a `toString()` method and therefore cannot be printed.

So **test** if you get an object or a string before you try to `echo` the return value.

Answer (score 0):

What @toscho means is that here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_parents

It clearly states that

> Return Values
>
> (string|WP_Error)
>
> The categories, separated by $separator. WP_Error on failure.

So you can't assume the output will be string and echo it. It can also be a WP_Error object. You need to test it using:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_wp_error